# Writing GIFs and videos from JPGs using Magick is slow and of poor quality

Tags: r, imagemagick, rmagick

I often write something like 300 frames that I want to make into a 20 second animation using the magick package in R. I am finding that to write the frames to a 300 jpegs and then bringing them into photoshop is more reliable than working with either image_write_gif or image_write_video.  Nevertheless, I would like to do everything in R and hope that someone has a suggestion for something more robust.

There is a similar question "slow or failed writing image vector to *.gif with magick in R?"  That question does not include a reproducible example and has not been answered.

I have experimented with image_write_gif and image_write_video as well as image_write.  It takes about 10 times longer to write the gif and write the video than to just write the images.  Also, in the examples below you get a smooth gradation of grey in the individual images, but the graduation breaks down a bit in the gif and the mp4 and there is some flickering.

```
library(magick)
pic1 <- image_blank(600, 600, pseudo_image = "gradient:white-black")
pic1 <- image_convert(pic1, format = "jpeg")
stack <- image_morph(c(pic1, image_negate(pic1)), frames = 100)
length(stack)

a <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:length(stack)) {
  image_write(stack[i], path = paste0("test", i, ".jpg"))
}
b <- Sys.time()
b - a

a <- Sys.time()
image_write_gif(stack, "test.gif")
b <- Sys.time()
b - a

a <- Sys.time()
image_write_video(stack, "test.mp4")
b <- Sys.time()
b - a
```

The first step (writing the individual jpegs takes about a half a second.  Writing the gif takes 6 seconds and the mp4 takes 4 seconds on my MacBook that is a 2018 vintage.

Comment: Have you tried the [animation](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=animation) package?  It's uses the [magick](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=magick) package too.  But it's worth a shot, in case its approach avoids the flickering.  BTW, I'm not seeing flickering when I run your code on my Windows 11 machine and open the mp4 & gif files with the built-in/free version of  [Clipchamp](https://clipchamp.com/en/).

Comment: It might run faster if you create your gifs (or modify them) so that they all have the same colormap. If not, Imagemagick has to work hard to look at 300 colormaps and convert them all down to one single 256 color color map. See the equivalent of -remap

Comment: A couple of clarifications. First, I am often working with full color photographs, so I would rather avoid the color mapping approach that a GIF uses.  I was thinking that the image_write_video would avoid this. Second, my bigger concern is the time it takes to render.  If I am working with a few hundred frames at higher resolutions, the 10 seconds can become 10 minutes. 10 minutes is fine if I don’t have to do multiple iterations…

Comment: I have tried the animation package, but it is mostly oriented towards graphics produced with plot or ggplot./. I couldn't figure out how to get it to work for photographs (jpegs).

Comment: If you are working with GIFs they only permit 256 colors. So you must reduce the number of colors. One way is to append a selection from the range of all your images into one GIF image and get its colormap. Then use -remap to assign that colormap to all the gif images before you make your animation.  But natural full color photographs are not terribly amenable to GIFs without a loss of quality. Video also has its issue with compression. So again a loss of quality. Perhaps an APNG animation might do better?

Comment: I was always surprised that image_write_gif produced good results for photographs. Looked into how the function works a bit and it seems to just wrap gifski.  This function does seems to use "pngquant's efficient cross-frame palettes and temporal dithering with thousands of colors per frame."  The results are good, but it is time consuming and huge file sizes.